# Run method before route

Tags: vue.js

I have a login modal that I activate by setting `.is-active` to it. For this, I have a method like this:

```
methods: {
    toggleModal: function (event) {
      this.isActive = !this.isActive
    }
  }
```

that I run onclick. Depending on the boolean value of `isActive`, my modal gets the class `.is-active`.

Thing is, in my modal I have a button that takes the user to a new view which means it's rendering a new component, with this code:

`<router-link class="control" @click="toggleModal()" to="/register">`

As you can see, it's routing to `/register`. Before doing this, I need to run `toggleModal()` so that the modal gets closed. Right now it's routing without running the method which means that the new view has my modal overlay which is... not optimal.

Is there any good way to do this in Vue? Could I maybe create a method, that first calls `toggleModal()`, and then routes from the method?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would define a method that calls toggleModal first, then navigates. Like so:

```
methods: {
  navigateAway () {
    this.isActive = !this.isActive
    this.$router.push('/register')
  }
}
```

You don't need the `event` argument unless you intend on capturing more data from the event or event target. You could also wrap the router push in a setTimeout if you so desire, for perhaps cleaner looking view changes.

```
methods: {
  navigateAway () {
    let vm = this
    vm.isActive = !vm.isActive
    setTimeout(function () {
      vm.$router.push('/register')
    }, 50)
  }
}
```

---

Of course, there are hooks that you can use from `vue-router` that make this easy. Example (assuming you're using single file components and Vue.js 2.x):

```
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      isActive: false
    }
  },
  beforeRouteLeave (to, from, next) {
    this.isActive = false // I assume that you would not want to leave it open upon navigating away
    next()
  }
}
```

Link to vue router hooks: https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/navigation-guards.html